# Can the edit distance of two binary numbers of unequal length be approximated with a Mathematical technique?

Tags: math, bit, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I am trying to efficiently find the closest binary number from a list of binary numbers to a given binary number. The binary numbers I am working with contain no consecutive zeros and 3 consecutive ones at max. I have tried the following techniques

1. Calculate their absolute difference and count the set bits.
2. Get the remainder from the division of the two numbers (greater/smaller) and count the set bits.

These seem to be working all right for the most part especially the second one but I was wondering if there were a more sophisticated technique that could produce more accurate results.

Comment: In the title you mention "unequal length"; are these lengths very different? For instance, do you know that the numbers in the list are very short, while the given binary number is very long?

Comment: No, the lengths aren't very different. I don't even bother calculating the distance if the length difference is greater than 5.

Comment: Did you try hamming distance?

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately gives atrociously bad results since the numbers aren't equal in length.